# std::map find not working in C++

Tags: c++, string, c++11, stl, omnet++

I have created a hash map and an iterator using the below lines:

```
std::map<const char*,vaLueClass *> myCache;
std::map<const char*,vaLueClass *>::iterator myCacheIterator;
```

Then I insert into this map using the below line:

```
myCache[anotherObject->getStringKey()] = new vaLueClass(anotherObj1->getIntAttr(), anotherObj1-->getIntAttr());
```

Then whenever I tried to search if an ENTRY for a particular string exist in this map or nut using below lines, it always enters the **IF** block which in other words it does not find any entries inside this map.

```
myCacheIterator= myCache.find(sampleObject->getstringKey());
```

NOTE: here `sampleObject->getstringKey()` returns the same key which has been inserted earlier.

```
if (myCacheIterator.operator ==(myCache.end())){
   // this block means that no matched entry is found inside the map myCache
}
```

Also, is this the proper way to create and use std::map in C++ ? If not then please suggest one.

Also, I have not used the keyword `new` to create the std::map object.

Comment: Are you trying to compare the string data or the address the pointers hold?

Comment: I want to check if an entry exist in this map with a particular (const char *) key

Comment: @user3243499 If you want to use strings and keys, use strings as keys, not `const char *`.   In other words, use `std::string` as key values.

Comment: ok, if I use `std::string` instead of `const char *` then please suggest a sample replacement of my IF(condition) statement in order to check if a particular string key exist or not in my hash map

Comment: @user3243499 Why do you think you need to change anything?  The `map::find` works correctly if what you're returning is a pointer to a (null-terminated) character sequence.

Comment: (Aside: please do not use the `>` quote formatting device as a general highlighter. This is widely understood to mean something that someone/something else said e.g. a paragraph quoted from a manual, an error quoted from the screen, etc. Thus it is confusing for readers who will wonder where it is a quote from).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a `std::map`, the keys are compared using the less-than `operator <` when performing a search. Since you're storing `const char*`'s as keys, this means that the lookups will compare the pointers themselves rather than the strings they point to, so if you don't pass in the exact pointer used to insert into the map, the lookup won't find anything.

I think the easiest fix here is to use `std::strings` as your keys, since the `<` operator on `std::string` actually compares the underlying text. That should fix your problem pretty quickly.

Comment: In this line `myCache[anotherObject->getStringKey()] = new vaLueClass(anotherObj1->getIntAttr(), anotherObj1-->getIntAttr());` the `anotherObject->getStringKey()` actually returns a `const char *` and I use this to insert in this map. So when I use the find method I might be using a different `const char *` pointer but have the same string. What should I do to achieve this ?

Comment: As suggested, use a `std::string` and not `const char *`.  Problem solved.  Also, you could have the same character sequence pointed to by different `const char *` values.  Nothing stops the compiler from giving the string-literal "xyz" a different address than "xyz" found somewhere else in your program.

Comment: It worked perfectly after changing it from `const char *` to `std::string`. Got my concepts cleared. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have several options to fix that:

1) You can use std::string instead of const char *

```
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >
> class map;
```

2) Map declaration can be seen above. Third template parameter is compare functor. You can pass your map a custom functor to implement the right behavior.

3) std::less uses operator< . You can write operator< for const char * .